# Nesting div in <a> doesn't make the whole div a link

Tags: html, css

It only redirects to the url when I click on either the image or the text. But not the whole `<div>`. Any idea? Here's my code:

```html
<a href="someurl">
  <div class="story">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
    <div class="storyText">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to make the `a` block level element, you can do that by setting `display:block` in `a`

```css
a {
  border: solid red; /* demo */
  display: block
}
a:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5) /* demo */
}
```

```html
<a href="someurl">
  <div class="story">
    <img src="//placehold.it/100">
    <div class="storyText">
      <h1>title</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
        <li>list</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem but it's the correct answer. For some reason when the html renders on the browser it puts the closed `</a>` tag on the same line `<a href="someurl"></a>`, so doesn't let me nest a `div` inside it. If anyone has any possible solution please respond, otherwise i'll ask a seperate question.

Comment: can you show your real content? you might have another  `a` inside of the first `a` which is invalid

Comment: Yep that was the problem, thankyou very much. So it was just another `a` tag after the `ul`, like this: `<a href="#" class="username">username</a>`. Can you explain why this doesn't work and how I can add this `a` tag in?

Comment: [nested links are illegal](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.2)